# Pass Variable into location.href

Tags: html, angularjs, variables, location, href

I have a dynamic Url, and in my html i want to do something like this:

```
<a onclick="location.href='myVariable';"><span>Click here</span></a>
```

This spells out the word 'myVariable' in the URL instead of using the value of my variable. I have also tried:

```
<a onclick="location.href='{{myVariable}}';"><span>Click here</span></a>
```

I used the brackets since my application is using angularJS, but that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to do this in HTML? Rather than using an onclick javascription function?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a ng-href="{{myVariable}}"><span>Click here</span></a>
```

Comment: Better to use [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) `ng-href` instead of usual `href`.

Comment: @NechiK Thanks, I didn't know about `ng-href`. I don't use Angular but I use Riot which is similar to React so knew what was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @NechiK ! I originally did have ng-href in there, however, that also didn't work. Something funky going on with our application, which is why i resorted to the onclick ... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use an onclick event when clicking on an "a"-tag. The tag is used to hyperlink to another page. Use this:

```
<a href='myVariable'><span>Click here</span></a>
```

And if you´re changing the url, perhaps you should add a slash before 'myVariable':

```
<a href='/myVariable'><span>Click here</span></a>
```